# SharePoint Online Management Shell license plan: free to download/use?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I am looking for some insight about SharePoint Online Management Shell license plan. Can we download / use it for free?

Comment: You can download SharePoint Online Management Shell for free from this link:https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=35588

Comment: Question is "Can we download Powershell for SharePoint Online for free?"

Comment: @RahulChitte edited your post to make your question more evident. If I misunderstood your needs, please fell free to roll back the change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sharepoint online management shell to use some default powershell commandlets of sharepoint Online.

Link to download: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35588

Please let me know if you need more detail with respect to your need.

Happy Coding..

Comment: I think he was asking about the license program of the tool. More like "Can I use it freely ? Is there any limitation?". I assume this question was made to double check any legal implication that may occur from using the tool during daily work or from redistributing it to a third party (suppose you are a consultant/support company)